# Jmeter: How to count numbers of rows returned from a search (response or gui)

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter i need to perform a large search and count the number of rows which are returned. Max rows are 50000. 
The number of rows which are returned are shown on the website after a search. "Number of returned rows: xx".
Or I can count the rows inside the HTTP response.

I have tried to use a regex post-processer to count the amount of rows which are returned, the problem is that JMeter freezes since the http-response is so large.

I have also tried to extract the text directly from the website unsuccesfully. I guess one cant do that since the information is not in the HTTP-response?

--So:
Is there some faster and less demanding way to counter all the returned rows inside a HTTP-response body?

Or is there some way to get the text directly from the website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application is buggy, I don't think that returning 50000 entries in a single shot is something people should be doing as there is creates extra network traffic and consumes a lot of resources on server and client(browser) side. I would rather expect some form of [Pagination](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/split-the-contents-of-a-website-with-the-pagination-design-pattern) when it comes to operating large amounts of data.

If you're totally sure that your application works as expected you can try using [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) which is available since [JMeter 4.0](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-4-0-released-td5727575.html)

Due to the specifics of internal implementation it consumes less resources and acts faster than the Regular Expression Extractor therefore the load you will be able to conduct from a single machine will be higher.

Check out [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) article for more information

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get that count in matchNr which is coming after search string. use Regular expression to match any name or id,

do match No. -1

ex. regex variable name is totalcount so then you can fetch that count by using ${totalcount_matchNr}